# Algorithm - Find the midpoint of an arc

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

In the diagram below, I need to find the midpoint M of the arc from A to B:

[image: midpoint]

I want to find M in terms of the following information:

- A.X and A.Y, the coordinates of A
- B.X and B.Y, the coordinates of B
- Radius, the radius of the arc
- Center.X and Center.Y, the center of the arc

How do I compute the coordinates of M?

Comment: There literally isn't a question here.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. How far did you get on solving it?

Comment: The question is how to what  algorithm i need to use to find the X and Y of the midpoint of the arc?

Comment: and no i don't have the attitude of the mid point

Comment: It is quite simple! Why is the question blocked?

Comment: Just a hint. Convert A and B to polar coordinates relative to the center. Find the formula for M in polar coordinates (radius is the same), convert back to cartesian. When the question is available again, I can give you the answer.

Comment: Isn't this maths rather than programming?

Comment: See: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/RR/database/RR.09.10/akulov3.html

Comment: @EmmadKareem what does it mean by x intercept ?

Comment: You may search for and use: arc midpoint computation
**OR**
arc midpoint algorithm
**OR** arc midpoint calculator whichever fits better into your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `A`, `B`, `M` and `Center` are objects of some vector type with the usual operations:

```
var a = A-C;
var b = B-C;
var m = a+b;
```

`m` is a vector that goes from `Center` towards `M`. Therefore:

```
m = m.Normalize() * Radius;
M = Center + m;
```

Please note: This algorithm does not assume an order of A and B, and always interprets the arc as the smaller of the two possible ones. Without adding special cases, it can only handle arcs with an angle smaller than 180°.

To handle order: First calculate the angle from a to b using [atan2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999):

```
var angle = Math.Atan2(b.y, b.x) - Math.Atan2(a.y, a.x);
if (angle < 0)
{
    angle = 2*Math.PI + angle;
}
```

Then [rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) `a` by half that angle:

```
angle /= 2;
var m = a.Rotate(angle);
M = Center + m;
```

Comment: There's a better answer without goniometric calls that is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103405/what-is-the-algorithm-for-finding-the-center-of-a-circle-from-three-points?rq=1

Comment: @Goodies Center of a circle isn't center of an arc.

Comment: @kagronic when the arc is *not* elliptical, we are talking about the same midpoint. The submit I refer to is a straightforward three points center calculation applicable on any circular segment. Call your math teacher if you think this is invalid.

Comment: @Goodies The midpoint of an arc is on the edge of the circle, the center of the circle is in the middle of the circle. They are totally different things. And that question uses 3 points this uses 2 points and the radius.

Comment: @kagronick you are right I confused M and center. But when the center (Xc, Zc) is known, the midpoint M of the arc above can be found easily as M=(Xc, Zc+distance(C, A)). When the arc is tilted, you can connect A and B, find the middle and orthogonal, normalize then multiply the vector with sagittal height to find M. In any case, calculating C first will help to find M too.

Comment: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/RR/database/RR.09.10/akulov2.html