# How to calculate the centre point of a circle given three points?

Tags: javascript, geometry

I am using Javascript and I know the positions of 3 points. I wish to use these to find out the center point of a circle.

I have found this logic (Not the chosen answer but the one with 11 upvotes) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213658/get-the-equation-of-a-circle-when-given-3-points

But I can't seem to get my head around how to write the logic for it.

I can't use bounding box by the way, this has to be done using the three points :)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Here's a solution in Java that seems to work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103405/what-is-the-algorithm-for-finding-the-center-of-a-circle-from-three-points

Answer (score 5):

**My favorite resolution**:

Translate the three points to bring one of them at the origin (subtract `(X0,Y0)`).

The equation of a circle through two points and the origin can be written

```
2X.Xc + 2Y.Yc = X² + Y²
```

Plugging the coordinates of the two points, you get an easy system of two equations in two unknowns, and by Cramer

```
Xc = (Z1.Y2 - Z2.Y1) / D
Yc = (X1.Z2 - X2.Z1) / D

D = 2(X1.Y2 - X2.Y1), Z1 = X1²+Y1², Z2 = X2²+Y2²
```

to be translated back (add `(X0,Y0)`).

---

The formula fails when the three points are aligned, which is diagnosed by `D = 0` (or small in comparison to the numerators).

---

```
        X1-= X0; Y1-= Y0; X2-= X0; Y2-= Y0;

        double Z1= X1 * X1 + Y1 * Y1;
        double Z2= X2 * X2 + Y2 * Y2;
        double D= 2 * (X1 * Y2 - X2 * Y1);

        double Xc= (Z1 * Y2 - Z2 * Y1) / D + X0;
        double Yc= (X1 * Z2 - X2 * Z1) / D + Y0;
```

Comment: is is possible to produce a fiddle with this working ? http://jsfiddle.net/ no worries if not ill try put one together when i have time :)

Comment: @thatOneGuy: no.

Comment: haha only 7 years later

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Gaurav Ojha in the comments I found this solution : [What is the algorithm for finding the center of a circle from three points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103405/what-is-the-algorithm-for-finding-the-center-of-a-circle-from-three-points)

And changed it to work with Javascript :

```
function CalculateCircleCenter(A,B,C)
{
    var yDelta_a = B.y - A.y;
    var xDelta_a = B.x - A.x;
    var yDelta_b = C.y - B.y;
    var xDelta_b = C.x - B.x;

    center = [];

    var aSlope = yDelta_a / xDelta_a;
    var bSlope = yDelta_b / xDelta_b;

    center.x = (aSlope*bSlope*(A.y - C.y) + bSlope*(A.x + B.x) - aSlope*(B.x+C.x) )/(2* (bSlope-aSlope) );
    center.y = -1*(center.x - (A.x+B.x)/2)/aSlope +  (A.y+B.y)/2;
    return center;


}
```

All you need to do is pass it 3 points :

```
 var threePoints = [{x:1, y: 2},{x:4, y: 4},{x:6, y: 2} ]

console.log(CalculateCircleCenter(threePoints[0],threePoints[1],threePoints[2]))
```

To get this answer :

```
[x: 3.5, y: 1.5]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Will fail when points are on the same vertical (and be inaccurate when close to the same vertical).

Comment: Good point, worked for me for what I needed it for. If you have a better solution, please explain :D thank you